# How can I get the key value equals to function parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a exercise I can't solve the way it must be solved. My solution didn't accept.

Can anyone explain to how can I solve this in another, maybe easiest way?

My solution, that work well, I think.

```
for name, place in friends.items():
    if place == city: #print text
```

Function code:

```
def is_anyone_in(friends, city):
    if city in friends.values():  # if city in collection
        for name in friends:  # loop thru keys of collection
            if   #  if key value equals city. This part I can't complete
                print('In city of ' + city + ' lives ' + name + '.')
    else:
        print('No one there.')

friends = {
    'Mike': 'Moscow', 
    'Kate': 'San Francisco', 
    'Dan': 'New York', 
    'Molly': 'Los Angeles', 
    'Stan': 'London'
}

is_anyone_in(friends, 'New York')
```

Expected result: 'In city of New York lives Dan.'

Comment: Should the line `for name in city:` be `for name in friends:`? `city` is a string. Also, it's not clear to me which part of this you are expected to complete and which part is "fixed".

Comment: Yeah, it must be ```for name in friends```. 
In function code I didn't provide my solution, sorry for that.
But @knock_out solution works well!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code with the least modifications:

```
def is_anyone_in(collection, city):
    if city in collection.values():
        for name in collection:
            if collection[name] == city:
                print('In city of ' + city + ' lives ' + name + '.')
    else:
        print('No one there.')

friends = {
    'Mike': 'Moscow', 
    'Kate': 'San Francisco', 
    'Dan': 'New York',
    'Molly': 'Los Angeles', 
    'Stan': 'London'
}

is_anyone_in(friends, 'New York')
```

A few things to note:

1. This code is inefficient.
2. We should do `collection.values()` instead of `friends.values()`. (Otherwise no need to pass it as a parameter.)
3. It should be `for name in collection:` instead of `for name in city:`. (`for name in city:` iterates over the characters of `city` and not the dictionary.)

Comment: Oh my god! I've been so stupid to not noticed that. We must pass collection (!!), just like function parameter! 

One of my not working solutions was almost the same as yours!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a reverse`dict` and do simple lookup like,

```
$ cat lives.py

from collections import defaultdict

friends = {
    'Mike': 'Moscow', 
    'Kate': 'San Francisco', 
    'Dan': 'New York', 
    'Molly': 'Los Angeles', 
    'Stan': 'London',
    'Meg': 'London'  # to demonstrate two friends staying in same city
}

def is_anyone_in(friends, city):
    city2friends = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in friends.items():
        city2friends[v].append(k)
    names = city2friends.get(city)
    if names is not None:
         print('In city of {} lives {}'.format(city, ', '.join(names)))
    else:
        print('None of my friends lives in city of {}'.format(city))

is_anyone_in(friends, 'New York')
is_anyone_in(friends, 'London')
```

Output:

```
$ python lives.py
In city of New York lives Dan
In city of London lives Meg, Stan
```

Comment: You should generate `city2friends` inside the function definition, not outside.

Comment: Because `is_anyone_in` could be called with a dictionary, not just `friends`.

Comment: I don't know about this approach. What if you have multiple friends who live in the same city? Suddenly you've lost data.

Comment: @han solo, In the `friends` dictionary, both key and value are strings. I'm saying that if the input data were different, where multiple people lived in the same city, your code would drop all except one person who lives in that city, because now the city is the key and a key can only have one associated value.

Comment: @hansolo Better, but that still doesn't solve @user10987432's point. You could have something like `{'Pete':'New York', 'Mary':'New York'}` which wouldn't work with your approach. You could do something like `city2friends = [k for k,v in friends.items() if v==city]` though, and just iterate over the items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_anyone_in(friends, city):
    if city in friends.values():
        for name, city1 in friends.items():
            if city1 == city:
                print('In city of ' + city1 + ' lives ' + name + '.')
    else:
        print('No one there.')

friends = {
    'Mike': 'Moscow',
    'Kate': 'San Francisco',
    'Dan': 'New York',
    'Molly': 'Los Angeles',
    'Stan': 'London'
}

is_anyone_in(friends, 'New York')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_anyone_in(mydict, city):
    ''' find city in mydict '''
    names = (k for k, v in friends.items() if city in v)
    for name in names:
        print('In city of ' + city + ' lives ' + name + '.')

# data
friends = {
    'Mike': 'Moscow', 
    'Kate': 'San Francisco', 
    'Dan': 'New York', 
    'Molly': 'Los Angeles', 
    'Stan': 'London'
}

# function call
is_anyone_in(friends, 'New York')

# result
>>> In city of New York lives Dan.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
friends = {
    'Mike': 'Moscow', 
    'Kate': 'San Francisco', 
    'Dan': 'New York', 
    'Molly': 'Los Angeles', 
    'Stan': 'London'
}

city = "New York"

friends_in_city = [friend for friend in friends if friends[friend]==city]

for friend in friends_in_city:
    print(f"{friend} lives in {city}")

if not friends_in_city:
    print(f"Nobody lives in {city}")
```